# Making world map with terrain colours in QGIS

Tags: qgis, cartography, mapping, color, terrain

[image]

In QGIS I would like to create a world map that has terrain colours (e.g., deserts or vegetation), as in the attached map (Gehring et al. 2022), particularly for the African continent.

How should I proceed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Download it as ready made background maps from [Natural Earth](https://www.naturalearthdata.com/):

- Large and medium size: https://www.naturalearthdata.com/downloads/10m-raster-data/
- Small size: https://www.naturalearthdata.com/downloads/50m-raster-data/

All maps and data are [free to use(!)](https://naturalearthdata.com/about).

Comment: Cannot believe that someone down-voted this. It is useful and direct.

Comment: Indeed, it is often unclear why someone downvotes. So in general for a downvote to be helpful, it should come with a comment, explaining: why was it downvoted? Does the solution not work? Is it misleading? Does the answer not attempt to solve the problem (not the case here, as OP accepted it). Downvoters should always consider that they have a very reason in mind, but for others, it can be difficult to find out what that was. Without any comment, the downvote does not help me to write better solutions in the future - or was the intention that this kind of answer should'n be posted at all?